# im getting Error response as 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: php, rest, api, curl

I'm getting  Error response as 405 Method Not Allowed while trying with PHP CURl Please find my below Code and help me I'm critical condition

```
<?php
    $credentials = "xxxx:yyyyy"; 
    $a=base64_encode($credentials);                   
    $url = "http://api.trust.in/get/token"; 
    $page = "/get/token"; 
    $headers = array( 
            "POST ".$page." HTTP/1.1", 
            "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8", 
            "Content-Length:0",
            "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials),
            "Connection:keep-Alive",
            "Host:xyz.abc.in"
        );
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    print_r(get_headers($url));
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a link for the API documentation? You are using the HTTP method POST which make sense to get a Token but would be good to check the API reference. Can you also confirm your endpoint: http://api.trust.in/get/token ?

Comment: Yes, the api documentation would be helpful. A thing that might happen that I can think of without seeing it would be that you are connecting using HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: @maxime_039 : Endpoint url is correct, please help me to solve this issue

Comment: @SriP strangely I cannot resolve the host api.trust.in. As explained please provide the API documentation so we can check.

Comment: @SvenBuis: here is the Doc luminpdf.com/viewer/9PomF8PEc4jWFsETq

Comment: This documentation is private. I cannot access to your link.

Comment: @maxime_039: Please help me

Comment: @SriP I posted an answer. I'm however not sure you should share publicly this documentation. It seems that some information are confidential. You should remove the link.

Comment: @maxime_039 Please  let me know Where you have posted the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130402/discussion-between-maxime-039-and-sri-p).

Comment: @maxime_039: my code sending GET request , i'm not able to find how to senr POST request

Comment: How do you know that? What steps did you follow?

Comment: at the end of the code i'm printing this one `$CurrentURL1="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
  echo  $CurrentURL1;`

Comment: Is there any chance of apache issue

Answer (score 1):

do not set you header content-length become zero, should give length of parameter that you post to site, to test it you can use postman. it easier to know what you doing wrong using that.

Comment: how write code for Postman method, Please send me sample code

Comment: "There is no request query parameters required for this request" based on the documentation, so the Content-Length can stay at 0. It's just POST method that is required for this endpoint but without parameters.

Comment: Please help me, still i'm facing issue

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation you provided, the url used for the API endpoint is not correct.

Instead of:

```
http://api.trust.in/get/token
```

Use:

```
http://api.toyotautrust.in/get/token
```

Please try that and give us the results.

Answer (score 0):

Added empty array `$params` because of zero parameters for POST Request according to my document 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));